# Multiple conditions with.ReplaceAll

Tags: java, replaceall

Is there any way to add multiple conditions to the .replaceAll?
Right now I am trying to convert the letters on a phone to the numbers they correlate to using .replaceAll. 
So far the snippet looks like

```
Scanner kbIn = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter the phone number: ");

String fakeNum = kbIn.nextLine().toLowerCase();

String returnNum = fakeNum.replaceAll("[abc]", "2");
```

So when you enter an a, b or c, it changes it to a "2" in the output. My question is- can you set multiple of these conditions in one line? Lets say I wanted to have d, e and f translate to 3 when printed. Can I do something like

```
String returnNum = fakeNum.replaceAll("[abc]", "2" && "[def]", "3");
```

I know this doesn't work- I am just using the boolean operator to symbolize that I am trying to work both of these conditions upon fakeNum. Is there a way to do this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why do you want to perform multiple operations in a single action? Do you think chaining calls is too verbose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option that I see is chaining the `replaceAll()` calls, like this:

```
String returnNum = fakeNum.replaceAll("[abc]", "2").replaceAll("[def]", "3");
```

Answer (score 3):

Chaining calls to `replaceAll()` will work, but you'll scan the string 8 times. I would just iterate over the string the old fashioned way:

```
public static String replaceDtmf(String str)
{
    if (str == null || str.isEmpty()) {
        return str;
    }

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        switch (Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(i))) {
            case 'A':
            case 'B':
            case 'C':
                result.append('2');
                break;
            case 'D':
            case 'E':
            case 'F':
                result.append('3');
                break;
            case 'G':
            case 'H':
            case 'I':
                result.append('4');
                break;
            case 'J':
            case 'K':
            case 'L':
                result.append('5');
                break;
            case 'M':
            case 'N':
            case 'O':
                result.append('6');
                break;
            case 'P':
            case 'Q':
            case 'R':
            case 'S':
                result.append('7');
                break;
            case 'T':
            case 'U':
            case 'V':
                result.append('8');
                break;
            case 'W':
            case 'X':
            case 'Y':
            case 'Z':
                result.append('9');
                break;
            default:
                result.append(str.charAt(i));
                break;
        }
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works just fine as well, but chaining them works in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Branching off of Sean Bright's answer, this will *"convert the letters on a phone to the numbers they correlate to"* as stated in the question.

I often approach problems through fast indexed lookup where a switch statement would also work, but a switch is (usually) more appropriate if you're handling default / "otherwise" cases.

```
private static final char[] keys = {
                                    '2', '2', '2',      // A B C
                                    '3', '3', '3',      // D E F
                                    '4', '4', '4',      // G H I
                                    '5', '5', '5',      // J K L
                                    '6', '6', '6',      // M N O
                                    '7', '7', '7', '7', // P Q R S
                                    '8', '8', '8',      // T U V
                                    '9', '9', '9', '9'  // W X Y Z
                            };

public static String replaceDtmf(String str)
{
    if (str == null || str.isEmpty()) {
        return str;
    }

    str = str.toUpperCase();
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        int index = str.charAt(i) - 'A';
        if (index >= 0 && index < keys.length) {
            result.append( keys[ index ] );
        }
        else {
            result.append( str.charAt(i) );
        }
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

See it on [IDEone](http://ideone.com/k2jose).

Comment: So trying to convert `1-800-AWESOME` will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`? And you're doing that intentionally?

Comment: So, it wan't meant as production code; just demonstrating the indexed approach — but if you insist; updated.

Comment: OK, the way I read your answer it seemed that throwing an exception was a feature. I understand now.

Comment: @Sean it all depends on the purpose... however if I wanted it to throw an exception on whatever one considers to be non-translatable I'd probably pattern-match and throw IllegalArgumentException if the input was "bad".